# How to trigger clientside javascript from a serverside C# code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-side, server-side

In an ASP.Net site, I want to use some javascript - let's say the `alert()` function - after what happens in an event; I want to be able to use the event parameters in the javascript. For example:

```
protected void SomeEventName(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
   int parameter = 0;
   // Do event stuff, which might effect the parameter
   javascript.alert("In the end of the funtion, the parameter is: "+parameter); // made up syntax, kids do not try this at home.
}
```

Problem is, the event is server-side and the javascript is client-side. Is there any way I can still do this?

Comment: [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) or web sockets.

Comment: Can you provide some more details on what you are tying to achieve?

Comment: @EmmanuelN For the sake of the question, I want to be able to run an event from a component in an ASP web page - let's say a button - and inside the event (not onclientclick - I want to use it IN the server code), trigger an alert which has something that's saved on the server-side.

Comment: This is what SignalR does.  Go use it.

Comment: Are you  familiar with Ajax? Make call to the server without refreshing a page, server returns some sort of data, execute JavaScript after the completion of Ajax call ...

Comment: @EmmanuelN Sounds intresting... that might help me. If you'll show me how to prompt a parameter from the server, even after the event, I'll award you with the checkmark. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register some JavaScript to be executed as soon as the page is loaded like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SomeUniqueTextHere", "yourJSFunction();", true);
```

**EDIT**

As for parameters, you can definitely pass parameter(s) from C# to JavaScript like this:

```
int parameter = 0;
string parameterStr = "hello";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SomeUniqueTextHere", string.format("yourJSFunction({0}, '{1}');", parameter, parameterStr), true);
```

Notice that you JavaScript function should be defined to accept two parameters in this example. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yourJSFunction (val1, val2) {
        alert(val1);
        alert(val2);
    }
</script>
```

Also, it's worth noting that [HiddenField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) controls can be used to pass string values between client and server:

ASPX:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MyHiddenField" runat="server" Value="MyValue" />
```

JavaScript:

```
alert(document.getElementById("<%= MyHiddenField.ClientID %>").value);
```

C#:

```
string value = MyHiddenField.Value;
```

In order to transfer complex C# objects, consider stringifying them into a [JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) string and then [parsing](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) them in JavaScript

Finally, the idea of executing server and client side codes Sequentially contradicts the design of HTTP protocol. The best you can do is use advanced JavaScript/C# tools where manipulating the communication between the two environments becomes easy. [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) comes to mind in this case.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm asking for. I dont want startup script, I'm looking for something that will run a script inside an event.

Comment: So, are you trying to call/execute a client side function inside a server side function??? why???

Comment: You cannot do this. you either call JavaScript before the post back or after. Remember that [web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be handy in order to execute server code without causing a page refresh. Also, you can have a look at SignalR for advanced real time scenarios.

Comment: @yazanpro I understand. Well then, perhaps it's impossible. That'd be the solution for me then.

Comment: @A.Abramov I provided my answer with more details to fulfill the concept of your question.

Comment: @yazanpro That is more detailed, but it's not exacly what I wanted. I used it in a solution I've found for myself - however , the question was put on hold, so... yeah. here's a +1. (:

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
this.GetType(),
"scriptsKey",
"<script type='text/JavaScript' language='javascript'>alert('" +parameter+ "');</script>");
```

Comment: As it seems, just like yazan's answer, this code executes only on the page load. My aim is to run a script inside an event function.